# Kripke Structure Intuition

Tags: logic

I was studying about Intuitionistic Logic and I saw that instead of assignments, there we use Kripke Structures. My Question is: Why can't we use boolean assignments to define Intuitionistic Logic aswell ? Why do we have to define Kripke  Structures ?

Sorry if this question is a bit unclear.

Comment: How would you avoid the excluded middle?

Comment: Maybe defining the $\lor$ operator somehow else ?

Comment: @abcd - Then you're just defining some other kind of algebra, probably a Heyting algebra, in terms of a Boolean algebra; it's not actually a Boolean valuation if you're not using the Boolean algebra's join operation.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I think there's some space for nontriviality here, e.g. why can't there be a two-valued algebra with different truth tables from classical that gives intuitionistic logic?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen - No reason, a priori; but then it wouldn't be a Boolean valuation is the point, since a Boolean valuation is more than just taking, as values, elements of a set for which there exists a Boolean algebra structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign Boolean values to your propositions, then you just have classical logic again, which sort of defeats the point. What you want for intuitinistic logic is for your propositions to take values in a [Heyting algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra), where excluded middle/double negation elimination doesn't necessarily hold.

So where do Kripke frames come in? Note that one of the things that has to be true about an intuitionistic Kripke frame $(P,\leq)$ is that we have $$p\leq q,\;p\Vdash\varphi\implies q\Vdash\varphi$$ for all $p,q\in P$ and propositions $\varphi$; that is, the set of conditions that force a proposition are closed upwards. In any partial order, the set of upwards-closed sets form a complete Heyting algebra under the appropriate operations, so that what we're really doing with a Kripke frame is assigning to $\varphi$ the Heyting truth value $\{p\;|\;p\in P\wedge p\Vdash\varphi\}$.

One of the reasons it's nice to work via Kripke frames, as opposed to dealing directly with Heyting algebras of various sorts, is that the way we define $\Vdash$ (and therefore, the way we define the Heyting truth value of each proposition in the model) is by giving a *classical* valuation associated with each $p$, which can be easier to think about. Our Heyting-valued assignment then comes about from the way these classical valuations are related to each other by the frame $(P,\leq)$.

Comment: So is there a way to systematically check all kripke frames? Like in classical logic we can check all assignments to check if a formula is satisfiable?

Comment: That's a good question! And the answer is that you can check satisfiability for propositional logic, though not necessarily by checking all Heyting truth value assignments. The method I know is by using tableaux, which isn't quite the same as giving a valuation. The obstacle to just checking (Heyting-valued) truth values is that there are no *finite* Heyting algebras $H$ such that something is true under every valuation in $H$ if and only if it's true under every valuation in every Heyting algebra, which contrasts with the classical case.